# accessing inputName attribute of ng2-completer

Tags: angular

How do I access the inputName attribute ofng2-completer?  I need to have more than 1 search box in my project, therefore my dataservice needs to be aware of which ng2-completer is calling it.  Otherwise I need a separate  dataservice for each ng2-completer.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Aren't you calling different httpcalls, therefore you would separate all searchboxes just by that?

Comment: discussion on this question is in this github [issue](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/issues/109)